# Should I advise colleagues about a booster shot?

Tags: professionalism, australia

Is it proper etiquette to inform your work colleagues that you are getting a covid booster shot in the future and you may be put out of commission on that day?

Or should you keep it to yourself?

I am not asking about company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies. I am also not asking about the law.

For the purposes of the question, you can assume an Australian workplace, though I'm happy enough to receive answers that are generally of a western culture, as I think it's broadly applicable to my situation.

I am considering telling my boss, and also some peers that may be impacted.